# Why do i get 2 default characters in my password input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a little problem....  see here : http://prntscr.com/5anqx8 : here you can see what's wrong, there are 2 default characters in those inputs... this happends on multiple pages and there is nothing in the code what could be the problem. I use Firefox but have Chrome as well. On Chrome is doesn't show these characters which is kinda weird. How do I get rid of these Characters?? I've tried clearing all history cache and stuff, the whole list. I restarted Firefox.... nothing works. I'm not sure if this is really a programming question but you guys are really smart so... I'm asking you :p

Thanks a lot,

Mike

CODE :

```
<!-- Right Content -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-box">
        <div class="titles">
            <h4>Registratie Formulier</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Form Contact -->
        <form class="form-theme">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Uw gebruikersnaam</label>
                        <input type="text"  required="required" value="" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="Name" id="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Uw email</label>
                        <input type="email"  required="required" value="" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="Email" id="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Uw wachtwoord</label>
                        <input type="password"  required="required" value="" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="Password" id="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>Herhaal uw wachtwoord</label>
                        <input type="password"  required="required" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="Password2" id="password2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Registreer" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- End Form Contact -->
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Right Content -->
```

Comment: Saved password? Tried private window?

Comment: wow i feel so terribly stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers can save form data like passwords, names and adresses.

When getting errors like this, remember to test in a private window/session to rule this out.

Comment: I have to wait 6 minutes to accept you answer so after 6 minutesill accept